# Is it possible to set an uploaded file name in GCS using Blobstore API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I'm trying to save a file in google cloud storage using Blobstore API in my servlet.

That worked but the problem is that the file name in GCS is not the same as the original file name was (Seems that it's just blobkey).

Can I do the same but have the original file name in GCS?

Answer (score 0):

I just recently went through the same process and after some head scratching was able to figure things out.  Check this link for my answer.
[google app engine java error using blobstore api to retrieve file from cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873949/google-app-engine-java-error-using-blobstore-api-to-retrieve-file-from-cloud-sto)

The short version is that your callback servlet needs to use the string returned from the method getGsObjectName().

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Troy. It might be helpful, however I can't make file stored in GCS to have the same name as was originally. And thus when a user downloads back his file, its name would differ. Seems it's just the way the blobstore works.

Comment: Hello Ant-nrd.  Yes, the name in the store is the long key string but when you download the file it downloads with the actual filename.  What I did in my callback was to save the name of the file(s) that were uploaded into a separate mapping object that stored the key string from the cloud store and the filename that was uploaded.  This way I can show the user the names of the files available and when they click the link I provide I simply use the key string to grab the file and stream back to the user.

Comment: Hello Troy. Its actually works fine to show the user the actual file name and giving link of its stored location in GCS with the separate mapping object that you created. But, the problem is, when the user tries to download it, it actually, downloads with the name stored in GCS instead of the original filename we showed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I came to this:

**No**. In the GCS files are saved with generated key as its name. (But its possible to save original file name somewhere else)

Comment: Hello Ant-nrd, Did you find the way to save the original file name instead of long auto generated file name in GCS.? If so, can you please share that. Thanks.